# Update subset of properties of a kubernetes manifest file (eg. like nodeselector) programmatically

Tags: powershell, kubernetes

I have a few daemonSets running on my k8s cluster.
I want to add an additional property in all of the daemonSets' pod template spec programmatically, using powershell.

In specific, I want to "add" the following to to a few daemon sets:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        operator: Exists
        effect: NoSchedule
```

The existing things like containers, volumes, label selectors, etc should be as it already exists.
How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the YAML file first and apply the YAML file changes using the Code or Program with the **K8s** client.

Python client

**Example**

```
from os import path

import yaml

from kubernetes import client, config


def main():
    # Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper
    # utility. If no argument provided, the config will be loaded from
    # default location.
    config.load_kube_config()

    with open(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "daemon-deployment.yaml")) as f:
        dep = yaml.safe_load(f)
        k8s_beta = client.ExtensionsV1beta1Api()
        resp = k8s_beta.create_namespaced_deployment(
            body=dep, namespace="default")
        print("Deployment created. status='%s'" % str(resp.status))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```